# How to make Opencv SVM faster?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

I am using Opencv 2.4.8 to implement an image classification solution.

No. of Classes = 29

No. of test images = around 4000

Features: SURF descriptors, after diving each image into 3x6 grid. This gives 18 different lists of SURF descriptors.

Classifier: CvSVM (NU_SVC/C_SVC) C=32, gamma=8

There are 18 classifiers, 1 for each grid block.

The final output is based on importance voting of outputs of all the 18 classifiers for all the SURF descriptors.

The problem is the SVM classification is taking a lot of time (around 600ms per image). The IEEE paper that proposed this technique reports a speed of 21fps. My implemented program's speed is 8-10x times slower.

Where could I be making a mistake?

Are there any suggestions to speedup my testing/classification?

Comment: Can you run each classifier in a parallel thread?

Comment: Yea, thats possible.
But I have Core i5 (4 cores), how much is max expected speedup ?

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot give you a definite statistic, but if you write it well enough, 3-4x is expectable.

Answer (score 2):

Many things may differ between your implementation and the authors implementation, but i would classify them in three main categories:

-The data: 
Do you use the same data that the authors of the paper?
Are you features exactly the same?
Maybe your data contains more classes, or are more difficult to classify, resulting in more support vectors?
If you don't use the same data and the data they use are publicly available, you may want to test your implementation on those data.
If they specify the number of SV in the paper, check that you get approximately the same number.

-The algorithm:
Are you using the same kernel and training parameters?
The OpenCV implementation uses a 1-vs-1 algorithm for multi-class classification, is it the same in your paper? 
Note that for 29 classes it will result in the evaluation of 406 binary classifier for each of the 18 classifiers, which may be one cause of your problem.

Edit: After having a quick look at the opencv code, it definitly uses 1vs1. 
It could be (one of) the problem, even if 1-vs-1 is usually reported as faster than 1-vs-all in the few papers i have seen about the subject (more classifiers, but globally less SV).
Considering your comments, the features are maybe a more probable cause, but without more details, or a reference to the paper, it's hard to say more.

-The implementation:
Maybe their implementation is simply better optimized/multi-threaded. I am not sure about the level of optimization of the OpenCV implementation. It is based on a quite old version of libSVM, but has probably been modified/optimized since. If it really is the problem, you may also want to consider GPGPU : http://mklab.iti.gr/project/GPU-LIBSVM

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply Adrien!

- The data: I use the same dataset as published by the paper

They do not report the # of SVs. Another thing is, that the feature vectors r basically SURF descriptors. They do not report the SURF parameters --> which effects number of features produced.

-The algorithm:
The paper uses RBF kernel, with Gamma=0.0825, and svm_type is NU_SVC. They do not report the "nu" value.

Are you sure OpenCV uses 1-vs-1 for multiclass? I thought I read on opencv docs that it uses 1-vs-all?

Comment: As for the implementation:
They didnt report using multi-threading. But I highly doubt they might have used multi-threading. They dont mention anything about GPU either.

Comment: From your comment, SURF can be one of the differences. And so is the `nu` value.

Comment: I am not sure to understand how you use the SURF features. Do you use a vector of SURF descriptors as input feature of the SVM. If yes, how do you choose the lenght of the vector? Maybe a reference to the paper could help.